# Carpet coloration specific parts

Tags: color

[image]

Hi!

I made a carpet and I am looking to add a color on specific part.

I tried brush but it is not satisfaying.

Looking for something like this: https://youtu.be/kv0q6EPJHKk?t=242

Thanks

Comment: have you considered [similar](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127894/creating-a-patterned-carpet)

Comment: Thanks very Much. I did not created a new mesh because I wantted to keep this. So I just made a simple texture and add it to the mesh.

Comment: Doesn't the video you linked teach that?

Comment: Check the video the quality is too bad it is impossible to read how he did it. He made something with the Node Shader Graph. Ratt's answer was what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to Ratt :have you considered [Creating a patterned carpet](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127894/creating-a-patterned-carpet)

Thanks very Much. I did not created a new mesh because I wantted to keep this. So I just made a simple texture and add it to the mesh:
[image]
[image]