# Create a rug mesh and apply a picture on it

Tags: modeling, mesh, materials

I'm coming from the software engineering world and I'm noob with anything related to graphics. I have a project where I want to be able to create a mesh that defines a rug/carpet, and then be able to choose a picture and map it onto the rug and see how it exactly would look like on it. Basically being able to be as realistic as possible. So, something like the Nike design studio, where users can design their shoes, interactively and see how would it look like.

I'm not sure where to begin, so thought maybe someone can guide me with steps that probably I should take to get there.

Comment: So you wanna apply texture to a rag? Or like, put an image to a thing that looks like rag?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/203035/how-to-add-a-texture-to-the-emitter-surface-of-a-hair-particle-object-over-ridi https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127894/creating-a-patterned-carpet